# can't figure out what's wrong with this sql query

Tags: mysql, pdo

Trying to get a list of the latest forum posts from a user, ordered by the date it was made.

The problem is posts are split between topics and replies, so i need to get the reply text from a different table if the latest post isn't the topic itself.

Trying to use CASE to switch between a subquery if it's a reply else use the topic text.

```
SELECT
    t.`topic_id`,
    t.`topic_title`,
    t.`last_post_date`,
    t.`last_post_id`,
    CASE WHEN t.`replys` > 0 THEN (
    SELECT
        `reply_text` AS 'text'
    FROM
        `forum_replies`
    WHERE
        `post_id` = t.`last_post_id`
) ELSE t.`topic_text` AS 'text'
END
FROM
    `forum_topics` t
WHERE
    t.`approved` = 1 AND t.`forum_id` IN (1) AND t.last_post_user_id = 1
ORDER BY
    t.`last_post_date`
DESC
LIMIT 5
```

The error is:

> ## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>
> near 'AS 'text' END FROM
>       `forum_topics` t WHERE
>       t.`approved` = 1 AND t.`f' at line 13

Comment: You cannot use subquery in this fashion inside a `CASE .. When` expression. If you can explain what you are actually trying to do, with some relevant and minimal sample data; with expected output. There may be other ways to achieve the same.

Comment: I think you should use `END CASE` instead of `END`

Comment: @ThomasHuijzer `END CASE` is required only when using in a context of Stored procedure/function or Triggers. Please refer: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html  "There is also a CASE expression, which differs from the CASE statement described here. The CASE statement cannot have an ELSE NULL clause, and it is terminated with END CASE instead of END."

Comment: `ELSE t.topic_text AS 'text' END` should be `ELSE t.topic_text END AS 'text'`. I do that all the time.

Answer (score 0):

Use of subquery in `CASE` is not allowed. Use `LEFT JOIN` instead:

```
SELECT
    t.`topic_id`,
    t.`topic_title`,
    t.`last_post_date`,
    t.`last_post_id`,
    t.`reply_text` as 'text'
FROM
    `forum_topics` t
    LEFT JOIN `forum_replies` r on r.`post_id` = t.`last_post_id`
WHERE
    t.`approved` = 1 AND t.`forum_id` IN (1) AND t.last_post_user_id = 1
ORDER BY
    t.`last_post_date`
DESC
LIMIT 5
```